# Combining multi-row excel records into table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, data-manipulation

I'm quite new to VBA and trying to combine multiple row records in a large data dump into a single row record with multiple headers.

The data is exported into an excel file from another program and takes the form of:

```
Order   Item    Qty
1       Item1   2
1       Item2   5
1       Item4   1
2       Item1   1
2       Item2   2
2       Item3   5
3       Item1   4
3       Item2   5
3       Item3   1
4       Item2   2
4       Item3   1
5       Item1   1
5       Item2   1
5       Item3   1
6       Item1   4
6       Item2   4
6       Item4   2
```

Which would then be sorted into:

```
Order Item1 Item2   Item3   Item4
1       1       4           1
2       1       2       5   
3       4       5       1   
4               2       1   
5       1       1       1   
6       4       4           2
```

I'm not expecting anyone to write my code but any pointers as to an overall approach would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would use a "do while" loop where I would check for the current and next order id. While consecutive order ids are identical, I would check if the corresponding item was added to the row of items previously. If it had been added, write the corresponding quantity underneath it, else add the new item in a new column and write the quantity underneath that. The row index should increment once consecutive order ids are not identical. You should also sort the order ids so that identical ones follow each other. Good luck. (Pivot table would be simpler, QHarr is right)

Comment: how does the bottom come from the top? Doesn't look right to me. I was going to suggest a pivottable as the simplest way but the result does not correspond.

Comment: @QHar, they do correlate, except for Order 1 (probably a typo?)

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yah if typo yes. I ran a pivot and expected exact match, Perhaps I should have adjusted text to _doesn't quite match_ ...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I create helper column and formula to get the counting. Hope can help.